# How do properly use css's "calc()' with ng-style

Tags: css, pug, calc, ng-style, angularjs-ng-style

I have the following inline-styling using Angular's ng-style and css's "calc()', but it didn't work. Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

```
// my jade file has a class named '.logo-area'. 
.logo-area(ng-style="{'right':'calc(100% -'+({{fixedWidth}}+'px') +')'}")
```

Comment: Looks like you would need to leave an extra space after the minus sign at least.

Comment: Right. the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc) page on calc mentions this specifically: "The operand of `calc(50% -8px)` for instance will be parsed as a percentage followed by a negative length, an invalid expression"

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me in HTML with Angular 8

> ```
> [ngStyle]="{'width': someAngularVariable +'px', 'left': 'calc(100% - ' +someAngularVariable + 'px)' }"
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
.logo-area(ng-style="{'right': 'calc(50% - '+{{fixedWidth}}+'px'+')'}")
```

Will solve the problem.

Comment: You should explain why changing the percentage will solve the problem.

Comment: The difference is a removed pair of parentheses.